# How to prevent clang-format from indenting comments that start at column 0?

Tags: clang-format

I want clang-format to not indent or change at all any comments that start at the beginning of a line.

The reason is that in Eclipse I can comment and uncomment a line by typing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd> but if once commented and then indented by clang-format and then uncommented the final indentation is wrong.

Any ideas on how to do it?